# How can I enable the binary log tabin phpmyadmin 5.0.1?

Tags: mysql, sql, logging, phpmyadmin

Well, I'm trying to locate the log file to check errors in phpmyadmin interface and I saw in posts and forums that phpmyadmin have a binary log tab to check it, but I don't have enabled that tab and the solutions I found don't have any real solution to me...
Thanks yall!

Comment: Do you control this MySQL server, or do you rent it from a service provider? Service providers don't let their customers see the binary logs. If they did, then customers would have access to one another's data. At any rate, ask the  person who controls the server about this, not us.

Comment: yes I control it @O.Jones I'm just getting into spring, ajax, etc

Comment: maybe this helps? you'll have to turn on binary logs in mysql, then change the phpmyadmin configuration to show them. https://serverfault.com/questions/209650/phpmyadmin-logs

Answer (score 1):

The Phpmyadmin application does not have a log file, however you can perform this trick:
Phpmyadmin has a php script that when executed will return a result with the errors you find.
On Ubuntu Server the file is in:

```
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/error_report.php
```

then you must enter that folder and run

```
php error_report.php
```

this will return the errors that Phpmyadmin has, most of the time they are errors in the configuration file config.inc.php

Answer (score 0):

What problem are you seeing with phpMyAdmin that you hope to fix by viewing the log? You haven't really described what problem you're trying to solve, which makes answering your question a bit difficult.

There are a number of logs available, but the most direct answer about the log file to check regarding errors with phpMyAdmin is in your webserver's error log. Read on for more details, though.

If it's a problem within phpMyAdmin directly (or something that phpMyAdmin does with MySQL), it's usually shown directly on the screen as a friendly message. If it's something that breaks phpMyAdmin directly, it's logged through whatever means you have configured for PHP errors to be logged (usually directly to the webserver error log).

If you're having a problem with a query through MySQL, those are logged by MySQL through the MySQL error log, which is usually to a file in most systems I'm familiar with.

The binary log is not related to error logging, but is instead an ongoing transaction log where MySQL records ongoing queries ([docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-log.html), [more docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/binary-log-overview.html)). Based on your description, this is not what you're looking for.

Comment: well, I'm coding my first API and had a 400 error. A user of this forum asked me for the log info, and searching about it I found that some people had that tab directly in the interface and I don't, so I started investigating to end up asking here.

Comment: HTTP 400 is a Bad Request, not something I recall ever seeing directly from phpMyAdmin. Do you use it behind any kind of proxy configuration? Do you have any other pages serviced by the same web server, and if so do they work? Which web server are you using? How have you installed phpMyAdmin, through a package manager, prepackaged kit like XAMPP, or by downloading directly from the phpMyAdmin site? Try removing your `config.inc.php` for a moment to test if there’s a problem with parsing that (which would ordinarily throw a 500 error, but worth a shot anyway).

Comment: I'm working just locally, the 400 error was returned by chrome, and that user asked me for the log, so I just started to search what was that binary log and why doesn't appears on my phpmyadmin GUI. I installed it with XAMPP. Now it's just curiosity and know what can I do to have it and for what. What is that config.inc.php?

Comment: config.inc.php is the phpMyAdmin configuration file. Normally, it's in the same folder as all the phpMyAdmin files, but XAMPP may put the configuration somewhere else. The binary log is a MySQL log of transactions that's going to be unrelated to any sort of debugging you or the user are looking for. A 400 error won't normally be related to the database server at all, but if you would be looking for a log of queries, the MySQL query log would be more helpful than the binary log. When does the error occur, is there a particular action that causes it consistently? Is it any phpMyAdmin action?